# Ant documentation integration for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ant, documentation

Is there an option in Eclipse, or a plugin to install, to enable tooltip help for ant code?

I'd like to be able to hover over an element and get the documentation for it in a tooltip window, like you would for Java code, or get Eclipse to open the ant manual for that element.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse select the ant xml build file and right click and select the ANT editor as the Open with option. This editor supports the common ant tasks but since ant allows custom tasks there is no defined dtd or xsd for the xml file.

There is no way.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question  - unless what you mean to say is that there is no way. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Ant editor code intellisense `<Strg> + <Space>` is all, but sufficiant. You'll get a tooltip with i.e.
 the sentence "Writes a message to the Ant logging facilities." for `<exec>` task, but not the whole stuff
 from ant manual.
For more details use ant apidocs in `$ANT_HOME/docs/manual/api` or
 `$ANT_HOME/docs/manual/index.html`